# URL Rewriting doesn't work - Apache, local server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url

- I have an website on my localserver (with Apace) and i want to
  rewrite urls.
- I have .htaccess file.
- I have RewriteEngine ON (on Apache)

**index.php**

```
<a href="post.php?post=<?php echo $row['postID'];?>"><h4><?php echo $row['postTitle']; ?></h4></a>
```

When someone press on the title of post will be redirected to post.php/post=postID

I want to rewrite this url (localhost/post.php/post=postID) to something like that:

/localhost/post/postTitle or /localhost/post/postID

Preferably the first one.

How can I do that?

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^posts/([0-9]+)/?$    post.php?post=$1    [NC,L]
```

Nothing happens, when I press on the link, the url is the same (post.php/post=postID).

Comment: Well yeah, the rewrite rule rewrites e.g. /posts/45 to post.php?post=45, not the other way around. So you probably want to update your a href link to use the new URL structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a manual process to update your links. So, you'll want to change:

```
<a href="post.php?post=<?php echo $row['postID'];?>">
    <h4><?php echo $row['postTitle']; ?></h4>
</a>
```

to:

```
<a href="posts/<?php echo $row['postID'];?>">
    <h4><?php echo $row['postTitle']; ?></h4>
</a>
```

---

Update: As a note, people like to use the shorthand for just `echo`'ing content, E.g.

`<?=$row['postID']?>`

So it would become:

```
<a href="posts/<?=$row['postID']?>">
    <h4><?=$row['postTitle']?></h4>
</a>
```

Comment: I dont know if that works. I want to have a post page for everypost i have so that's why i made the post.php?post= url..

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. I assume you have made the page which outputs a single post, and you have made the `.htaccess` changes, so have you tried going to `posts/123` manually? If that works, then simply update the links in your files as demonstrated above.

Comment: I dont know how to explain this. I need to edit my links like Wordpress permalinks.. i have multiposts site and insted to /post.php/post=postID i want something like this /post/postTitle.. postID and postTitle are from database. In index.php are displayed the each post i have in database and when someone click to title of the post (that have a href to post.php) is going to post.php?post=postID..  :D  E.g : i have 3 posts (ID:1 Title: Hi, ID:2 Title: Yes, ID:3 Title: No) when someone click on Hi (the title of the post with id 1) is going to post.php?post=1 i need to change this url to /post/hi

Comment: Done.. i got it. Thanks! But i have a problem.. the content is ok but the style of the page isnt' .. i mean if i go to post.php?post=postID i have the right style of the page... but to posts/postID i haven't the style on this page..

Comment: It's probably because you have *relative* URL's for your CSS so it's looking in the wrong place. You could add `../` before the URL so it looks in the previous directory to what it thinks you are in, so you end up with `../my-styles.css`, or you could change them to *absolute* paths, so `/full/path/to/my-styles.css`.